# Spectral radius proof in a particular case of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces

A  norm on $L(\mathbb{R^n})$ is the uniform norm. This norm in defined in
terms of a given norm on $\mathbb{R^n} = E$, which we shall write as $| x| $. If $T: E \to E$ is an operator, the uniform norm of T is defined to be 
\begin{equation*}
||T|| = max\{|Tx| : |x| \leq 1\}
\end{equation*}
With this defintion of norm i want to solve that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a basis B of $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
||T||_B < \dfrac{1}{3} + \epsilon
\end{equation}
where ||T|| is the uniform norm of T corresponding to the Euclidean
B-norm on $\mathbb{R^2}$ and
\begin{equation}
T = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3} & 0\\
10 & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Apparently to solve the problem, i have to prove first that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to \infty} ||T^n||^{\frac{1}{n}} = \dfrac{1}{3} 
\end{equation*}
which i already did, and i know that the above quantity is the spectral radius, and i know that there is a theorem that give me exactly what i am looking for, but i would like to see how to apply that in a simple case or space as $\mathbb{R^2}$

What the theorem says is
Let $ A \in M_{n}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given. There is a matrix norm $||.||$ such that $\rho(A) \leq ||A|| \leq \rho(A) + \epsilon$

Where $\rho(A) $ is the spectral radius.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Look at the matrix of $T$ in the basis $(e_1,\ M\cdot e_2)$

Comment: sorry but could u tell me what is M?

Comment: Any number, preferably large